# supertest test delete method return 404 but restful client works

Tags: node.js

I use supertest to test my api, the delete endpoint works fine when testing with some restful client such as postman but failed in supertest.

```
it('should return 200', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .del('/v1/xxxx/' + id)
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200, done);
    });
```

But it pass the test when I add

```
it('should return 200', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .del('/v1/xxxx/' + id)
            .send({})
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200, done);
    });
```

Can some one tell me why?

Comment: I get same behaviour currently, I thought it was just me setting up supertest incorrectly but I cannot see why it works fine via fiddler but not via supertest.

Comment: I have the same problem and am investigation... and will report back.

Answer (score -1):

It is unclear from your post what this issue may be exactly.  The most likely is that the '/v1/xxxx/' url is incorrect.  Could it be '/api/..../v1/xxx/'+id ????

In my own case, that was the issue. AND I can report that supertest works exactly as expect for .del(...) or .delete(....).

I hope this helps someone else that hits this snag.